# How to get data grid view using only jsp and my sql database

Tags: mysql, jsp

i want to take data from database as grid view.
i m using jsp and do not have knowledge about struts or any other higher feature than jsp.
Can any one give me the proper program with proper description/tutorial for why/how to use that program.

please provide the source code as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You have many options -

- front end - use a javascript library e.g. dojo
- use backend to render

Personally I would go the dojo or similar route

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/datagrid/

The grid rendered in javascript offers many options and keeps your display logic encapsulated.

Comment: if i want to know by using backend for grid view,

Comment: There are backend frameworks too for example https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp

Comment: can you please tell me simplest way to get data grid view for jsp and mysql